# Running pimcore on a node.js-server

Tags: node.js, pimcore

Has anyone ever tried running pimcore on node.js? And if yes: is it running and was it much work?

I have a big PIM-system with many many hits and I want to keep it as slim and fast as possible. So I thought of node.js but I'm not quite sure if it ends up in rewriting class after class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pimcore requires PHP - it is not possible to run it on node.

Comment: Basically you're right but there are ways to integrate node.js with PHP. I know this is not superb, but I just want to run some tests.

Comment: @StephanWeinhold you could give this a try: https://github.com/mkschreder/node-php . Although I would never suggest to use this outside of an experiment. Pimcore is a PHP project and to make sure it runs stable, it should absolutely run on a PHP server. Plus, it lets you optimize the performance a whole lot and PHP 7 is landing sometime soon

Comment: @GNi33 node-php merely passes php scripts to the php interpreter. Of course it is possible to use node as a webserver and to use php for the php.
There are ways to run PHP in JS - https://code.google.com/p/phype/wiki/ThePhypeProject - but this won't work for a system like Pimcore.